# About removing the bootable USB

Tags: boot, usb, uninstall

If I install ubuntu in a USB, Can it be removed after and Use the USB normaly to save files, or once it's in it can't be removed ?

And I want to know if the USB can be used in saving files, videos, images... while Ubuntu is already booted ?

Comment: How did you "install" Ubuntu to the USB? Is it just a live USB / ISO copy, or a full install to the USB? Or did you use the USB to install Ubuntu to your hard drive?

Answer (score 2):

**While booted from the USB drive, it should not be removed**. (There is an exception: if you use the the boot option `toram`, and there is no persistence on the USB drive, the system data from the USB drive is copied to the RAM, and the USB drive can be unmounted and removed).

**After a normal installation (to an internal drive), the USB install drive is no longer necessary.** If it is mounted it should be unmounted (ejected, safely removed), and can be unplugged.

---

Depending on how the USB install drive was created it can or cannot be used to store data.

**A cloned drive has the ISO 9660 file system, which is read-only.**

Other alternatives make it possible to store files. A special case is a **persistent live drive**, where you can store files, but also install application programs.

You can even create an installed Ubuntu system in a USB pendrive, and it will behave like a system installed into an internal drive (but slower depending on the data transfer rate).

---

As mentioned in another answer, you can format the pendrive alias create a new partition table and file system to **restore it to a standard storage drive**.

---

See the following links for more details,

[Try Ubuntu (Kubuntu, Lubuntu, Xubuntu, ...) before installing it](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2230389)

[help.ubuntu.com/community/mkusb](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/mkusb)

Answer (score 1):

If the drive is Live, (non-persistent), and is booted toram it can be unmounted or removed and replaced while Ubuntu is running, but why, it is not necessary to remove and replace the drive to save files to it?

If the drive is made with **mkusb** it can have a FAT32 boot partition, a read only ISO9660 partition, (for th OS), an ext4 casper-rw persistence partition and a NTFS data partition that is accessible to both Linux and Windows.

It is not necessary to remove or unmount the drive to save stuff on it.

Answer (score 0):

Sure, when the installation finishes succesfully, you should be able to erase all the content in the USB or just format it because the files store in the HDD and the USB isn't used.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot remove the storage device on which you have a mounted filesystem. In particular, you cannot remove the storage device on which you have the `/` (root) filesystem... If I understand the question correctly, you intend to install the operating system on a storage device connected via USB. That storage device cannot be removed while the system is running.

For completeness: you can install the operating system *on* the hard disk (or on a USB drive) *from* a USB stick. That installation stick is not needed after the installation.

Answer (score 0):

The USB can still be used for storing files on any operating system (including Ubuntu running from the USB). If you want to remove the USB while running ubuntu, you will have to install it on to another storage device such as your hard drive/SSD. The Ubuntu installer allows you to use partitions to install it alongside an existing operating system.

Answer (score 0):

1. A USB flash drive is a **removable drive** so of course it can removed after Ubuntu running on the drive is shut down.
2. A full installation of Ubuntu on any device is **persistent** so any changes (files, installed software, etc.) on the USB drive are saved persistently across reboots.